# Making text bold based on page tree depth in Confluence

Tags: confluence

In Confluence Page Tree sidebar, is it possible to change the text to bold based on the depth of the Page tree?

For example:

-- General information

---- Background

---- Q&A

-- Testing process

---- Introduction

I'd like to have General information and Testing process written in bold in the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Confluence Server, you can do this. On Confluence Cloud, you are out of luck, sorry.

Add the following in **Confluence Admin | Look and Feel | Custom HTML** in **At the end of the HEAD**:

```
<style>
  ul.plugin_pagetree_children_list > div > ul > li > div > span {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>
```

This will be selective for *just* the first level of links in the pagetree and not for the children.